# Mechanize cookie_jar not saving session tokens

Tags: ruby, mechanize, mechanize-ruby

I'm using Mechanize to scrape a password-protected website upon user's request. I'm trying to decouple login and search functionality by running a Rake task that logs into the site and saves the cookies into a database, which is reused by subsequent Mechanize requests.

My problem is that `cookie_jar.save` method doesn't save session cookies/tokens into the cookies file. Here's a simple example that demonstrates this:

```ruby
require 'mechanize'

# Setup Mechanize agents
agent1 = Mechanize.new
agent2 = Mechanize.new

# Fetch page and save cookies to local file
agent1.get ('http://www.my-secure-website.com')
agent1.post('http://www.my-secure-website.com/login', {
    'user[login]' => 'my_login',
    'user[password]' => 'my_password',
    'submit' => 'Login'
})

# Verify and save cookies
agent1.cookie_jar.save_as 'cookies'
p agent1.cookie_jar
# #<Mechanize::CookieJar:0x8cf60b8 @jar={"www.my-secure-website.com"=>{"/"=>{"JSESSIONID"=>JSESSIONID=1NqLRc4dm0Qp5465N82Zwz4N0yXxy5jP1pXpyKp9jG8ssX2nMp5q!-334818122}, "/login/"=>{"Account"=>Account=my_account_number}}, "evr.my-secure-website.com"=>{"/APBDBQ"=>{"JSESSIONID"=>JSESSIONID=A74D230DEAFF50098557FBE76DD2E0C5}}}


########################################################
# Now let's load cookies into the second Mechanize agent

# Version 1 - This works only partially. Session cookies are missing:
agent2.cookie_jar.load 'cookies'
p agent2.cookies
# [
#    [0] Account=my_account_number
# ]
p agent2.cookie_jar
# #<Mechanize::CookieJar:0x914c658 @jar={"www.my-secure-website.com"=>{"/"=>{}, "/login/"=>{"Account"=>Account=my_account_number}}, "evr.my-secure-website.com"=>{"/APBDBQ"=>{}}}>


# Version 2 - This works, but cannot be saved into file/db!
agent2.cookie_jar = agent1.cookie_jar
p agent2.cookies
# [
#    [0] JSESSIONID=1NqLRc4dm0Qp5465N82Zwz4N0yXxy5jP1pXpyKp9jG8ssX2nMp5q!-334818122,
#    [1] Account=my_account_number,
#    [2] JSESSIONID=A74D230DEAFF50098557FBE76DD2E0C5
# ]
p agent2.cookie_jar
# #<Mechanize::CookieJar:0x8cf60b8 @jar={"www.my-secure-website.com"=>{"/"=>{"JSESSIONID"=>JSESSIONID=1NqLRc4dm0Qp5465N82Zwz4N0yXxy5jP1pXpyKp9jG8ssX2nMp5q!-334818122}, "/login/"=>{"Account"=>Account=my_account_number}}, "evr.my-secure-website.com"=>{"/APBDBQ"=>{"JSESSIONID"=>JSESSIONID=A74D230DEAFF50098557FBE76DD2E0C5}}}>
```

And this is what my saved cookies file looks like:

```yaml
---
www.my-secure-website.com:
  /: {}
  /login/:
    Account: !ruby/object:Mechanize::Cookie
     version: 0
     port: 
     discard: 
     comment_url: 
     expires: Thu, 22 May 2014 07:48:46 GMT
     max_age: 
     comment: 
     secure: true
     path: /login/
     domain: www.my-secure-website.com
     accessed_at: 2013-05-22 00:48:47.227628764 -07:00
     created_at: 2013-05-22 00:48:47.227628764 -07:00
     name: Account
     value: S4633
     for_domain: false
     domain_name: !ruby/object:DomainName
       ipaddr: 
       hostname: www.my-secure-website.com
       uri_host: www.my-secure-website.com
       tld: com
       canonical_tld_p: true
       domain: my-secure-website.com
     session: false
evr.my-secure-website.com:
  /APBDBQ: {}
```

You can see the session token (`JSESSIONID`) in the console output, but it's missing from the local cookie file. My question is, how do I make `Mechanize.cookie_jar.save_as` also save the session data?

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Updated to make the question clearer.

Comment: Session cookies probably shouldn't get saved. You want to patch Mechanize.cookie_jar to change that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of Mechanize version 2.6.0. the `cookie_jar.save_as` method allows passing of `:session` option to enable saving session cookies as well:

```
agent1.cookie_jar.save_as 'cookies', :session => true, :format => :yaml
```

P.S. I was using v2.5.1, which lacked this functionality.